# java.lang.IllegalStateException: GameHelper: operation attempted at incorrect state

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm getting the following exception using GameHelper class from Google Play Games Services.

**Logtrack:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GameHelper: operation attempted at incorrect state.
Operation: succeedSignIn. State: DISCONNECTED. Expected states: CONNECTING CONNECTED.
at ru.funapps.games.frutcoctail.GameHelper.assertState(GameHelper.java:185)
at ru.funapps.games.frutcoctail.GameHelper.succeedSignIn(GameHelper.java:781)
at ru.funapps.games.frutcoctail.GameHelper.connectNextClient(GameHelper.java:678)
at ru.funapps.games.frutcoctail.GameHelper.onConnected(GameHelper.java:777)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.v(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bp.v(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$f.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$f.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$b.A(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i read so many documents on this type of error....and i found that there is bug in google-play-services library so now how to get solve my problem...can anyone help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating to the latest version of GameHelper?

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples